# Há alguma distinção entre softwares que possuem base de dados ou não?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, software

Uma dúvida que me surgiu enquanto estou estudando e que ainda não encontrei algo sobre isso. Sabemos o que é um *software*, aqui uma breve [definição](http://www.ufpa.br/dicas/progra/protipos.htm):

> Um programa (em inglês, software) é uma sequência de instruções
>   específicas que descrevem uma tarefa a ser realizada por um
>   computador, na manipulação, redirecionamento ou modificação de dados,
>   de maneira lógica.
>
> Ess termo é utilizado tanto para o código fonte, escrito em alguma
>   linguagem de programação, como para o arquivo que contém a forma
>   executável deste código fonte.

Porém ele pode se relacionar com uma base de dados para gerar informações ou não, de qualquer forma ele não perde sua definição de *software*.

**Mas há algo que faça a distinção quando é utilizado um banco de dados?**

Comment: _"Database-backed software"_ e _"database-driven software"_ são formas em inglês de se dizer software suportado por banco de dados e software orientado a banco de dados, respectivamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posso estar enganado, mas acho que não existe. O termo é genérico mesmo. Existem definições boas e ruins por aí. Esta parece bem razoável.

Na verdade precisaria definir o que é um banco de dados para depois procurar uma distinção. O que a maioria das pessoas pensam ser um banco de dados provavelmente é uma definição específica demais e aplicada apenas a uma parte do que possa ser considerado um banco de dados. A própria [definição encontrada na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) é bem ruim porque tende para uma forma bem específica de banco de dados.

Não é bem um termo, mas se quiser nomear mesmo, chame de "programa para acessar/manipular banco de dados". Quem sabe "programa dirigido para banco de dados"? Dependendo do contexto (não parece ser o usado na pergunta) pode ser "programa gerenciador de banco de dados", ou simplificadamente "programa de banco de dados" (*database software*).

Acho que o nome dependerá mais do que ele faz de fato e não porque acessa banco de dados. É difícil porque, em geral, o acesso ao banco de dados é até uma atividade secundária, é um meio de atingir o fim. E o que é importante para definir o tipo de programa é a finalidade dele.

Embora possa ser muito estranho e quase inviável, alguns programas que se espera sempre trabalhar com banco de dados podem funcionar sem eles e atingir o mesmo fim.

Eu prefiro dar um nome de ERP, CMS, DNA Analyzer, ou coisa do tipo, é mais significativo que dizer que ele acessa banco de dados.

O tal do "gerenciador de banco de dados" (*database manager*) seria um programa cuja atividade fim é manipular banco de dados - possivelmente para auxiliar outros programas - por isso é mais fácil dar um nome para ele. Nem sei se esse é um bom nome, mas é bastante usado.

É comum, mas não obrigatório, que mais de um programa seja responsável por manipular um banco de dados. Claro que bancos de dados mais complexos tendem mais a isso.

Note a diferença entre programa e solução/sistema completo.

Bom, isso me parece ter pouca relevância. Pode parecer preciosismo o que estou respondendo, mas justamente achar um termo pra isso só cabe para o campo mais acadêmico mesmo.

De qualquer forma seria legal se alguém souber de algo mais específico, duvido.

Comment: Sim, bigown, seria apenas para o meio acadêmico.